# Sum using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

How i can get the result array using LINQ?

```
 int max = 500;
 int[] items = new[] {5, 7, 9, 1};

 int[] result = new[] {495, 488, 479, 478};


 //result[0] = max - items[0];
 //result[1] = result[0] - items[1];
 //result[2] = result[1] - items[2];
 //result[3] = result[2] - items[3];
```

Without LINQ i can do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
 if (i == 0)
    result[i] = max - items[i];
 else
    result[i] = result[i - 1] - items[i];
}
```

But i can'nt undestand, how to make it with LINQ
Have you any Idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is a task description. Can you please describe the problem which you have solving this task? Hint: you are looking for `Aggregate`

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: This is not a good SO question. Please explain what you are trying to do and what is the problem with your code

Comment: Why not just do this with a simple loop?

Comment: How is that task getting a "sum"?

Comment: You could simplify that loop to just `result[i] = max -= items[i];` if you don't mind mutating `max`.  If you need to leave `max` alone just assign it to a temp variable before the loop and use it instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a linq statement that will replicate what you did in your comments

```
var results = items.Select((x, i) => 500 - items.Where((y, j) => j < (i + 1)).Sum()).ToList();
```

Comment: @user3688343 This is not a good way of doing it. Where a simple scan through an `IEnumerable` suffices, you are scanning through the same list in a nested fashion, increasing the runtime complexity by an order, and worsening the readability of the code.

Comment: @user3688343 Vikhram is correct. but Vikhram did not read the question... it stated you wanted linq answer and that is what i gave you... so stop downvoting without reading mr Vikhram

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, LINQ does not provide this type of aggregation. Ideally, you want to write the aggregate function by yourself for this, using loops. A not so clean solution using LINQ would be as below

```
var results = new List<int>();
items.Aggregate(max, (agg, curr) => { var n = agg - curr; results.Add(n); return n;});
```

It is not clean, since we don't want to use LINQ to create side-effects, but mostly as a `PURE` function.

Updated with a better way to do it using an aggregate extension

```
static class Extensions {
    public static IEnumerable<TAccumulate> AggregateExtn<TSource, TAccumulate>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func) {
        TAccumulate result = seed;
        foreach (TSource element in source) {
            result = func(result, element);
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it as below

```
var results = items.AggregateExtn(max, (agg, curr) => agg - curr);
```

Comment: linq is not the right thing to use in this situation. sadly I do not know how to do aggregate or how it would work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following.

```
var result = items.Select(x => max -= x);
```

Complete Code

```
 int max = 500;
 int[] items = new[] {5, 7, 9, 1};
 var result = items.Select(x => max -= x).ToArray();
```

Output

```
495 
488 
479 
478
```

Comment: surely the best answer XD

Comment: The only downside is the side effects which ideally you want to avoid with Linq.

Comment: @juharr which is?

Comment: @Neil, it's changing the `max` variable.  So if you were to iterate `result` twice you'd get different results unless you reset `max`.

Comment: @juharr Thanks for bringing that up. But, if it was converted to an Array (as I left in comments) or list, the results could be retained right ?

Comment: @juharr Ahh that makes sense. you are correct. but you could just create a new temp variable on the fly and store it in there to avoid this.

Comment: @Neil That would solve the `max` variable changing, but iterating `result` twice would still have the same problem unless you reset the temp variable to max.  The best way to avoid that is to materialize the query immediately via `ToList` or `ToArray`.

Comment: @AnuViswan Yes, I'd definitely materialize any Linq query with side effects immediately for that very reason, but then you lose Lazy Loading.  It's just a matter of picking the trade offs you're willing to live with.